# Calculate fee for a given transaction

Tags: rpc, weight, fee, custom-rpc

is it possible to calculate the weight (and transform to fees) for a given transaction ?
I mean, I need to create a custom RPC method which will calculate that and return the fees.

Thank you

Comment: Interesting, why do you need this? Does https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/transaction-payment solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at this [How-to-guide](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/weights/calculate-fees/) in the Substrate website to see how to do it with the [Transaction Payment Pallet](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_transaction_payment/index.html).

Then you can apply this code to your pallet and create the custom RPC, I leave here a [guide about how to create a custom RPC](https://hackmd.io/JpJCbu0nTa2jym0za1Tggw) too.

Comment: thank you Alex, but its not really related to a pallet its for a transaction that we will pass as a parameter of our new custom rpc.

Comment: You can take a look about how the transaction payment pallet is doing it: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs#L485 to implement it yourself in your RPC code